# Selected date value is set to null after double click

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin

I am trying to take datetime value form cell of my appointment sheet. If I do it slowly (click, and  wait, than click again) it works. However, if I double click fast, it will not take cell time.
It will say that datime value is null or have old date if selected previsiously.

I´ve been trying to find some slution for days but found nothing. Any help please? :/

There is button that appears when clicked to cell.

Xamarin code:

```
<ContentView x:Name="Tab_Schedule">
        <syncfusion:SfSchedule x:Name="ScheduleDay" ScheduleView="DayView" DataSource="{Binding Appointment}">

            <syncfusion:SfSchedule.DayViewSettings>
                <syncfusion:DayViewSettings
                NonWorkingHoursTimeSlotColor="White">
                </syncfusion:DayViewSettings>
            </syncfusion:SfSchedule.DayViewSettings>

            <syncfusion:SfSchedule.SelectionView>
                <Button
                    x:Name="Button_Open_Add_Event"
                    BackgroundColor="Orange"
                    Text="+New Event"
                    TextColor="White"
                    Clicked ="Open_Add_Event"/>
            </syncfusion:SfSchedule.SelectionView>
        </syncfusion:SfSchedule>
    </ContentView>
```

C# code:

```
public void Open_Add_Event(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime SelectedTime = ScheduleDay.SelectedDate.Value;

        Timepicker_Add_Event_From.Time = SelectedTime.TimeOfDay;
        Timepicker_Add_Event_To.Time = SelectedTime.TimeOfDay;

        Tab_Add_Event.IsVisible = true;
        Tab_Schedule.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

[Schreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXHcd.png)

[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5KHE.jpg)

Comment: "t will say that datime value is null" - what **specifically** does this mean?  Is it throwing a NullValue exception?  On which **specific** line?  Have you considered adding some null checks or other exception handling logic?  On a sentinel flag to prevent it from executing multiple times?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added a schreenshot of the error. Also I did not add any null chceck beacuse that datetime needs to be set, if it is not set to specific time it the program will not work as intended to.

Comment: please do not post errors or code as screenshots

Comment: you still have not told us what the exact error is or which line causes it.  When you "double click fast" is it firing one event with a null and one without?  If that is the case then checking for and ignoring the null seems like a good strategy.

Comment: @Entity_45 I checked the code you provided. When i double click fast, no errors except the NEW EVENT add button. We need more details with screenshot.

Comment: The error message: System.InvalidOperationException
  Message=Nullable object must have a value.

Also added schreenshot. 

Hope it helps

Comment: The app crashes only if I double tap any cell ON START. If I will select other cells. It will not give error message, only the date will not update. It will stay old

Comment: I could reproduce the same error now. I use `TapGestureRecognizer ` instead. Please check my reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `TapGestureRecognizer` to instead to avoid the fast double click. The `TapGestureRecognizer` could set the `NumberOfTapsRequired` property to wait for a double-tap (or more taps if required).

Change:

```
<Button
                x:Name="Button_Open_Add_Event"
                BackgroundColor="Orange"
                Text="+New Event"
                TextColor="White"
                Clicked ="Open_Add_Event"/>
```

To:

```
  <Label
            x:Name="Button_Open_Add_Event"
            BackgroundColor="Orange"
            Text="+New Event"
            TextColor="White">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2" Tapped="Open_Add_Event" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
```